# Jar signing common name

Tags: jar, ssl-certificate, signing

I'm looking to sign a jar that will be launched via jnlp from different servers behind a firewall on an internal network. The jar file needs to be signed with a trusted certificate so as to avoid the security warning.

I've set-up keystores and SSL certificates in the past, but only to be used for web applications. Typically the Common Name used when setting up the key-pair should be the domain name pointing to the web application (e.g. mysite.example.com).

How does this change when signing a jar that will be served via jnlp from different servers that typically do not have domain names assigned to them. Is the Common Name as important here? Can we set-up and sign the jar using a single trusted certificate with one Common Name, to be used for all servers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally **we sign something with private key and we verify by public key**. Then it is a little bit different than trust a web (SSL) server.

The procedure:

1. create (get) key pair certificate
2. import on keystore
3. sign the jar

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html

Comment: We've signed the jar with a self-signed certificate. However, when launching with Java 7 we are prompted with a warning that the publisher is unknown. We need to eliminate this warning.

Comment: It depends; do you publish this jar on a public site? If yes you cannot pretend an auto acceptance of untrusted and not sured certificate by any user (it is obviuosly impossible). If it is only for debug purpose you have to trust the "chain of the authorities".

Comment: Obviously you can buy a valid certificate... ;-)

Comment: We plan to buy a valid certificate, but going back to the original question, does the Common Name in the above scenario play any role in validating the authenticity of the signed jar, the way it would in a web-app scenario?

Comment: No! No problem on this scenario!